# Autocad & System.Addin, FileNotFoundException for Autocads basic dlls

Tags: c#, .net, dll, autocad

i just started to develop applications for AutoCAD 2016. I want to load my dLLs into a separate AppDomain, so that i don't have to restart ACAD all the time.

After a lot of research and trying i ended up with a pipeline solution 
using System.Addin and System.Addin.Contract.

I use only interfaces and standardclasses for the Views Contract and Adapters like in this example [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb788290(v=vs.110).aspx).

This is my addin containing one methode to write Hello into Acad's Editor and a second methode for drawing a line.

```
using System.AddIn;
using CADAddinView;
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.EditorInput; 
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices;
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.DatabaseServices;
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.Geometry;

namespace CADAddIn
{
[AddIn("cadAddIn", Version = "1.0.0.0")]
public class CADAddIn : ICADAddinView
{
    public void drawLine()
    {
        Document acDoc = Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices.Core.Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument;
        Database acCurDb = acDoc.Database;

        using (DocumentLock acLckDoc = acDoc.LockDocument())
        {
            using (Transaction acTrans = acCurDb.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
            {
                DBObject blkTbl = acTrans.GetObject(acCurDb.BlockTableId, OpenMode.ForRead);
                BlockTable acBlkTbl = blkTbl as BlockTable;

                BlockTableRecord acBlkTblRec = (BlockTableRecord)acTrans.GetObject(acBlkTbl[BlockTableRecord.ModelSpace], OpenMode.ForWrite);

                Polyline acPoly = new Polyline();
                acPoly.SetDatabaseDefaults();
                acPoly.AddVertexAt(0, new Point2d(0, 0), 0, 0, 0);
                acPoly.AddVertexAt(0, new Point2d(100, 100), 0, 0, 0);

                acBlkTblRec.AppendEntity(acPoly);
                acTrans.AddNewlyCreatedDBObject(acPoly, true);

            acTrans.Commit();
            }
        }
    }

    public void sayHello()
    {
        Editor ed = Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices.Core.Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument.Editor;
        ed.WriteMessage("Hello");
    }
}
```

}

this is my HostApplication:

```
using System.AddIn.Hosting;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using CADHostView;
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.Runtime;

namespace CADHost
{
public class CADHost
{
    [CommandMethod("sayHello")]
    public static void sayHello()
    {
        string addInPath = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\Pipeline";
        string[] warnings = AddInStore.Update(addInPath);
        foreach (string warning in warnings)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(warning);
        }

        Collection<AddInToken> tokens = AddInStore.FindAddIns(typeof(ICADHostView), addInPath);

        if (tokens.Count == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No AddIn found.");
        }
        else
        {
            AddInToken cadToken = tokens[0];
            ICADHostView cadApp = cadToken.Activate<ICADHostView>(AddInSecurityLevel.Host);

            cadApp.sayHello();
        }
    }

    [CommandMethod("drawLine")]
    public static void drawLine()
    {
        string addInPath = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\Pipeline";

        string[] warnings = AddInStore.Update(addInPath);
        foreach (string warning in warnings)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(warning);
        }

        Collection<AddInToken> tokens = AddInStore.FindAddIns(typeof(ICADHostView), addInPath);

        if (tokens.Count == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No AddIn found.");
        }
        else
        {
            AddInToken cadToken = tokens[0];
            ICADHostView cadApp = cadToken.Activate<ICADHostView>(AddInSecurityLevel.Host);

            cadApp.drawLine();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Both of the two applications reference to three standard-Dlls from Acad:
accoremgd.dll, acdbmgd.dll, acmgd.dll.

In both projects these dlls have the option local copy false.
If i start then i get an Exception, where the programm cannot find the file "accoremgd.dll" and Acad crashes.

So i tried to set the Option local copy true only for the Addin.
Now it works for the "sayHello"-Methode.

but i get an invalide cast exception when acBlkTbl is initialised.

Would be great if someone has the last steps for me to make this work.
Also great would be a working example must not be made with the Addinsystem
i only want to make this work for not restarting acad all the time^^

Thank you for your help
matthias

Comment: if someone is interested i also can send the hole project per mail for testing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe a separate AppDomain will work, when you call AutoCAD object types it will go to the main AppDomain and get messed up...

As just want to edit your code and don't restart, you'll be better with [Edit & Continue feature](http://adndevblog.typepad.com/autocad/2013/06/coming-soon-x64-edit-and-continue.html) (available since VC2013 on AutoCAD 2015, I believe).

Comment: I will give this a try, but i want to try to finish this. I tested a few things more and it looks like that i have to do something to get information from Acad. Everything works fine, until i "ask" for information in the drawing. (getObject ...)

Comment: indeed that the problem, the second AppDomain will not communicate with the main AppDomain(AutoCAD main). Indeed we tried many different ways to unload a .DLL (assembly) from AutoCAD and could not find a way... sorry...

Comment: Ok, but perhaps you can tell me, just for unterstanding, why the sayHello - Methode works and the addin-dll is "free" after the call of sayHello...

Comment: probably because you're not calling "real" AutoCAD objects... in fact most of the API is thin layer over the C++ API that access deep acad objects, but some other pieces (like command methods) are fully implemented in .NET

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported. AutoCAD is a very old and complex program and most of the AutoCAD API objects cannot be used in remote fashion.

Please read:

1. http://through-the-interface.typepad.com/through_the_interface/2008/09/tired-of-not-be.html
2. http://forums.autodesk.com/t5/net/netload-is-there-a-net-unload-command/td-p/2404002
3. https://www.theswamp.org/index.php?topic=38675.0

In the #3, you can see that the AutoCAD development team confirmed that there are some global variables which will prevent working this way.

Comment: I came to this too and allready gave up my trys to find a solution with C#. Atm. im working on a autolisp-programm, where i can achive similar effect than unloading the dll. I'll keep you up to date after some testing on monday

Answer (score 0):

I gave up my tries to solve this problem. My current "best" solution is to load dlls at the start of AutoCAD. At least i don't have to netload every dll.
If someone has a better solution feel free to tell me^^ Thanks to all that answered. matthias